# WCF InstanceContext Usage

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

I am creating a WCF service. Consider my service might be requested 10K times per min. The hits may be from a fresh client or same user(repeated request). In this scenario which instance mode should i use and why?  Apart from sharing data members between clients Is there any other use of specifying single.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: But I am little confused with the load part. i.e., if the no. of request is huge then which one suits better and why?

Comment: According to the article you should go with PerCall option. in that way there is no shared state between calls and you have the opportunity to loadbalance etc

Comment: I definitly recommend that you do some loadtesting in a realistic scenario and environment, where you can try different settings and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

The answer as **Daniel Stackenland** has suggested in the comments is: *It Depends*.

The general consensus is that `PerCall` is the most scalable of the `InstanceContext` options as no state information needs to be maintained in between calls. However, if your service class constructor is doing a lot of work, then this work is going to be repeated for every single call. In this case, then `PerSession` might be the more appropriate option as this heavy activity in the constructor only needs to occur once per session.